Maximum value of $f(x)=(\cos x-x)\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+\sin^2x}\right)$

Maximum value of
$\displaystyle f(x)=(\cos x-x)\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+\sin^2x}\right)$

What I try : I am Trying to solve it using $\displaystyle 4ab\leq (a+b)^2$:
$\displaystyle 4f(x)\leq \left(\cos x+\sqrt{x^2+\sin^2x}\right)^2$
$\displaystyle 4f(x)\leq 1+x^2+2\cos x\sqrt{x^2+\sin^2 x}$
I am struck here and I did not understand how do I solve it  after that , please have a look , Thanks
Answer given is $0.5$

The same question was asked 9 days ago but that question was closed (entitled Maximizing $6\left(\cos x-x\right)\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+\sin^{2}{x}}\right)$; I posted an answer there). The link is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4899352/maximizing-6-left-cos-x-x-right-leftx-sqrtx2-sin2x-right.

Thanks River Li, But it shows page not found.

Yes, it requires >10K reputation score to view other users' closed posts.

@RiverLi you may post your answer here again.

@Amir Thanks. But my solution there is based on a guess maximum. Perhaps we need some process to reveal the maximum (with derivative or without derivative). Although I have another proof using derivative without a guess maximum, it is similar to the existing solution. So I don't put that answer here.

We have $f(0)=0$.
In the following, $x\not=0$ for which $\sqrt{x^2+\sin^2x}\not= 0$.
We have
$$f'(x)=\frac{\bigg(\cos x-x-\sqrt{x^2+\sin^2x}\bigg)g(x)}{\sqrt{x^2+\sin^2x}}$$
where
$$g(x):=(1+\sin x)\sqrt{x^2+\sin^2x} + x + \sin x\cos x$$
Let us consider $X$ such that $\cos X-X-\sqrt{X^2+\sin^2X}=0$. Squaring the both sides of $\sqrt{X^2+\sin^2X}=\cos X-X$ gives $X\cos X=\cos^2X-\frac 12$, and so
$$\begin{align}f(X)&=(\cos X-X)\bigg(X+\sqrt{X^2+\sin^2X}\bigg)
\\\\&=(\cos X-X)\cos X
\\\\&=\cos^2X-\bigg(\cos^2X-\frac 12\bigg)
\\\\&=\frac 12\end{align}$$
In the following, let us see if the following inequality always holds : $$f(x)\le\frac 12\tag1$$
We see that $(1)$ is equivalent to
$$(\cos x-x)\sqrt{x^2+\sin^2x}\le x^2-x\cos x+\frac 12\tag2$$
The RHS of $(2)$ is always positive since $$\text{RHS}\ge |x|^2-|x|+\frac 12=\bigg(|x|-\frac 12\bigg)^2+\frac 14\gt 0$$
So, for $x$ such that $\cos x-x\le 0$, the inequality $(2)$ holds where the equality of $(2)$ does not hold.
For $x$ such that $\cos x-x\gt 0$, we see that $(2)$ is equivalent to
$$\begin{align}&(\cos x-x)^2(x^2+\sin^2x)\le \bigg(x^2-x\cos x+\frac 12\bigg)^2
\\\\&\iff x^2\cos^2x+x\cos x-2x\cos^3x+\cos^4x-\cos^2x+\frac 14\ge 0
\\\\&\iff \frac 14(2\cos^2x - 2x\cos x - 1)^2\ge 0\end{align}$$
which is true.
So, we can say that $(1)$ always holds.
To prove that the equality of $(1)$ holds, it is sufficient to prove that there is $x$ satisfying both $\cos x-x\gt 0$ and $h(x):=2\cos^2x - 2x\cos x - 1=0$. We have $h(0)=1$ and $h(\frac{\pi}{2})=-1$, so there is $x$ satisfying both $0\lt x\lt \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $h(x)=0$. For such $x$, we have $\cos x - x=\frac 1{2\cos x}\gt 0$.
Therefore, the maximum value of $f(x)$ is $\color{red}{\frac 12}$.

You have
$$f(x)\leq \frac{1}{4}\bigg(1+x^2+2\cos x\sqrt{x^2+\sin^2 x}\bigg)$$
where the RHS is larger than $\frac 12$ when $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Nice +1. I wonder if we can shorten this proof.

I have got solution without derivative :
$\displaystyle x+\sqrt{x^2+\sin^2(x)}=t$
$\displaystyle \bigg(x^2+\sin^2(x)\bigg)= (t-x)^2=t^2+x^2-2tx$
$\displaystyle 2x=t-\frac{\sin^2(x)}{t}$
$\displaystyle f(t)=\frac{1}{2}\bigg(-t+\frac{\sin^2(x)}{t}+2\cos(x)\bigg)t$
$\displaystyle f(t)=\frac{1}{2}\bigg[-t^2+\sin^2(x)+2t\cos(x)\bigg]$
$\displaystyle f(t)=\frac{1}{2}\bigg[-\bigg(t-\cos(x)\bigg)^2+1\bigg]\leq \frac{1}{2}$

It is very nice.

You may also explain why $0.5$ is attainable for some $x$.
